# Get value between to hours from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, epg

I'm trying to get a specific show description from my DB but I really don't know how, I know i'm new into this, the table (guide) have 2 DATETIME values "start" and "end"

If I use this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guide WHERE start  >= CURDATE()");
```

Only return the first value from the table, and inclusive its the wrong value, please I need some help to get this, because I don't find a solution from other on this web

Comment: You should be able to use `between`. `select * from guide where now() between start and end`.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. It should be "value between **two** hours"

Comment: I'm trying to create some kind of TV Guide and I want to show the current show on air, but the shows have an "start hour" and a "end hour", and the only value that I have to get this is the current time like this: **2016-01-12 20:45:14** so my problem is how can I get the current show using that

Comment: @chris85 your solution works fine, now how I use a 3rd value for get the specific show? I mean the "channel" row, something like: `where channel = $channel_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use mysql's [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) function to pull the records in the current time range.

```
select * from guide where now() between start and end
```

To limit the returns you can add in additional parameters, this may give you back no results though so have a default value.

```
select * from guide where channel = $channel_ID and now() between start and end
```

You also should look into parameterized queries and updating your driver. Having variables in your query isn't the best practice.

Comment: Thanks to your first solution I ended using:
`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guide WHERE (NOW() BETWEEN start AND end) AND channel = 13");`

And works, this is OK or may cause any issue?

Comment: That query should be fine, depending on how your application runs it may display things strangely when no results are found/available though (or maybe that won't happen).

Comment: Thanks for you quick and really nice solution